# Applescript a Variable folder location for use on multiple desktops

Tags: pdf, applescript, acrobat

(I'm a real novice) I was able to create an apple script by culling together bits from other posts. This script batchprints PDFS from a folder using the acrobat pro 11 engine and moves them to a separate folder when complete... While the script works well on one computer where the desktop path is fixed. It must be modified for every different computer we use. Is there a way to script the watch folder in a variable location?

```
property myFolder : "HD:Users:User:desktop:Print:"

set myfiles to list folder myFolder without invisibles

repeat with myfile in myfiles

    set mycurrentfile to ((myFolder as string) & (myfile as string)) as string
    batchprint(mycurrentfile)

end repeat

on batchprint(mycurrentfile)

    tell application "Adobe Acrobat Pro"
        activate -- bring up acrobat
        open alias mycurrentfile -- acrobat opens that new file    
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Acrobat"
                click menu item "Print..." of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
                click button "Print" of window "Print"
                tell application "System Events"
                    tell process "Acrobat"
                        click menu item "Close" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell

    tell application "Finder" -- to move the printed file out 
        set x to (("HD:Users:User:desktop:Printed PDFs") as text)
        if alias x exists then
            beep
        else
            make new folder at the desktop with properties {name:"Printed PDFs"}
        end if
        move alias mycurrentfile to folder "Printed PDFs"
end tell


end batchprint
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AppleScript, you can refer the Desktop folder of the current user with `path to Desktop Folder`
E.g.:

```
set myFolder to (path to Desktop Folder as text) & "Print:"
```

Comment: that worked great!...Thank you.  Can you give me some guidance on how I format that in the second part of my script that creates the second folder "printed PDFs"

Comment: set x to (path to desktop folder as text) & "Printed PDFs" should work